# Drag down formula with n-step-increment

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to produce a sum for every seven entries of Column A, Sheet1, displayed in Sheet2. The point in which I'm stuck is how to define the formula the the formula-drag-down produces this formula with 7-step increments.

My table in Sheet1 looks something like this

```
     A    
1    1:00    
2    1:00     
3    1:00     
4    1:00     
5    1:00  
6    1:00     
7    1:00
```

and in Sheet2 in the respective cell there should be an entry `7:00` which sums *Sheet1.1-7* the next entry should sum *Sheet1.8-14*, the next *Sheet1.15-21* and so forth, all by dragging down the formula...

I think my solution is somewhat linked to the `OFFSET()` function, but I got stuck somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the formula

```
=(ROW($A1)-1)*7
```

somewhere and drag down, then you get the serie 0, 7, 14, 21, ...

This is because the dragging down will adapt `$A1` to `$A2`, `$A3`, ...

So

```
=SUM(OFFSET($Sheet1.$A$1,(ROW($A1)-1)*7,0,7,1))
```

will be the formula for your requirements.

Maybe you have to use semicolon `;` as formula separator instead of comma `,`.

```
=SUM(OFFSET($Sheet1.$A$1;(ROW($A1)-1)*7;0;7;1))
```

One Problem with this approach is that if you insert rows above row 1, then all the formulas which refers row 1 will be adapted. So `=(ROW($A1)-1)*7` will be adapted to `=(ROW($A2)-1)*7`. This will impact the functionality of this approach. To avoid this we can use

```
=(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1)*7
```

instead. With this, the adapting to `=(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1)*7` will not impact the functionality.